# Python code terminates while trying to run an exe file using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, executable, popen

I'm trying to run this exe:

```
s = subprocess.Popen('make.exe -console -verbose', stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Although I could have used subprocess.run here, but I need to run it in 'Unblock' mode as I have other parts of the code to execute simultaneously.

(PS: It is working fine with `subprocess.run` but in that case the rest of the code doesn't move further)

Answer (score 0):

The call to Popen is "non-blocking".  In other words, the sub process is created and Popen returns immediately.  If you want to do something with the sub process (like read output or simply wait for it to finish) then you can use one of the method calls from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects), such as wait() or communicate().

If you are happy to just wait for the end of the sub process, use wait(), with an optional timeout value:

```
# create the sub process
s = subprocess.Popen('make.exe -console -verbose', stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

for _ in range(6):
    try:
        # wait for 10 seconds
        s.wait(10)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        print("Waited 10 seconds, process still not done")
        continue

print("Tired of waiting")
s.kill()
```

Comment: The .exe file i use here has to run continuously in background. However with Popen, it just terminates as soon as it starts.

Comment: Then don't supply a number to wait.  If you call `s.wait()` then it will block indefinitely (until make.exe is terminated).

Comment: Yes I'm not calling s.wait(). But the problem is that the exe file gets terminated when subprocess.Popen() is called. Also, when I use subProcess.run(), the exe runs perfectly fine. But subprocessrun() cannot be used for 'non-blocking'.